# Como criar lista no Haskell

Tags: array, haskell

Como crio uma funçao que recebe um lista(pode ser dinâmica ou estática) e retornar o n-issimo elemento dessa lista? Utilizo a linguagem Haskell.

Comment: Essa função já existe ... mas você tem que implementar?

Comment: Você está aprendendo Haskell zero? StackOverflow não é o melhor lugar para começar assim, existem referências mais apropriadas: [Wikibook](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell) ou [LYaHfGG](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/), por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só precisas definir que a `lista` vai receber uma lista de um tipo qualquer.

Exemplo:

```
lista:: [a]->[a]
lista a=a
```

Comment: Muito obrigado meu Irmao

Answer (score 1):

O mais directo em Haskell é o operador `!!`

```
lista !! n
```

Para evitar que aborte caso `n` seja fora dos limites:

```
nesimo :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
nesimo _ []       = Nothing
nesimo 1 (x : _)  = Just x
nesimo n (_ : xs) = nesimo (n - 1) xs
```

`nesimo 3 [2,3,4,5,6]` daria `just 4`
e `nesimo 13 [2,3,4,5,6]` daria `nothing`

Comment: gostei da tua sugestão eu já pegar o penúltimo, olha o que eu fiz...

penultimo:: [l]->l

penultimo a = a !!((length a)-2)

Comment: @Arsenio, é esse o espírito: a partir dum problema, inventar novos problemas e novas soluções!

Answer (score 0):

Dada qualquer lista `xs`... você pode achar aqui a função que procura (está no item ***1.2***) e outras mais.

1. ***Básico***

   - **Obter o tamanho da lista.**  `length xs`
   - **Vire uma lista de trás para frente.** `reverse xs`

   1.2. ***Encontrar / procurar***

   - **Obter o enésimo elemento fora de uma lista.**  `xs !! n`

     (Relacionado: `head xs` retorna o *primeiro* elemento da lista.)

     (Relacionado: `last xs` retorna o *último* elemento da lista.)
   - **Obtenha uma lista de todos os elementos que correspondem a alguma condição.**  `filter my_test xs` 
     (Retorna tudo o que passa no teste.)
   - **Encontre o maior / menor elemento de uma lista.**

     `mínimo xs`

     `máximo xs`

     (Funciona não apenas para números, mas para qualquer coisa que seja membro `doOrdclasse`. Em particular, isso inclui caracteres e strings.

   1.3. ***Adicionando***

   - **Adicione um elemento ao início de uma lista.** `novo_elemento : xs`
   - **Adicione um elemento ao final de uma lista.** `xs ++ [ new_element ]`
   - **Insira um elemento no meio de uma lista.**

     Geralmente, você terá que dividir a lista em duas listas menores, colocar o novo elemento no meio e, em seguida, juntar tudo novamente. Por exemplo: `let ( ys, zs ) = splitAt n xs   em   ys ++ [ novo_elemento ] ++ zs`
   - **Junte-se a duas listas juntas.** `list1 ++ list2`

   1.4. ***Excluindo***

   - **Exclua os primeiros N elementos de uma lista.** `drop n xs`

     (Relacionado: cauda xsremove apenas um elemento.

     (Relacionado: init xsremove apenas o último elemento.)
   - **Faça uma nova lista contendo apenas os primeiros N elementos de uma lista existente.** `take n xs`
   - **Divida uma lista em duas listas menores (na enésima posição).** `splitAt n xs`

     (Retorna uma tupla de duas listas.)
   - **Exclua apenas o décimo elemento de uma lista.**

     Isso é complicado. AFAIK, não há nenhuma função interna que faz isso. Você tem que dividir a lista em dois, remover o elemento de uma lista e juntá-los novamente, assim: `let (ys,zs) = splitAt n xs  in  ys ++ (tail zs)`

     (Relacionado: `tail xs` remove o *primeiro* elemento.)

     (Relacionado: `init xs` remove o *último* elemento. *Lento, se a lista for grande*.)
   - **Exclua elementos que atendem a alguma condição.**

     Haskell tem uma função chamada `filter` que fará isso por você. Cuidado, porém: deve ser chamado de '*select*'. Por exemplo, `filter odd xs` retorna uma lista de números ímpares. Ou seja, elimina tudo o que não é estranho.

   1.5. ***Testando várias condições***

   - **Verifique se uma lista está vazia.** `null xs`
   - **Descubra se algum elemento da lista passa por um determinado teste.** `any my_test xs`
   - **Verifique se todos os elementos da lista passam em um determinado teste.** `all my_test xs`

   1.6. ***Modificando a lista ou seus elementos***

   - **Aplique uma função a todos os elementos da lista.** `map my_function xs`
   - **Aplique uma função apenas a alguns elementos de uma lista.**

     Supondo que você só quer aplicar a função `f` para elementos para os quais função p retorna true, você pode fazer isso: `map (\x -> if p x then f x else x) xs`
   - **Converta uma lista de foos em uma lista de barras.**

     Localize ou escreva uma função para converter *foo* em *bar* e aplique-a à lista inteira usando `map`.
   - **Numere os elementos de uma lista (para que eu possa processar cada um de maneira diferente de acordo com sua posição).** `zip xs [ 0 .. ]`

     (Por exemplo, `zip ['a','b','c'] [0..]` dá `[ ( 'a', 0 ) , ( 'b', 1 ) , ( 'c', 2 ) ]`.)
   - **Aplique uma lista de funções a um único elemento para obter uma lista de resultados.** `map ($ my_element) xs`
   - **Totalize uma lista de números.** `sun xs`

     (Relacionado: `product xs` irá multiplicar todos os elementos juntos em vez de adicioná-los.)
   - **Ordenar uma lista**

     Você precisará importar `Data.List` primeiro, mas você pode fazer `sort xs`.
   - **Descubra se algum item está em uma lista.** `my_element 'elem' xs`
     1.7. ***Listas e IO***
   - **Execute uma lista de ações de IO.**

     Transforme uma lista de IO em uma ação de IO que retorne uma lista de resultados: `sequence xs`

     ```
     Prelude > sequence [putStr "ola", putStrLn "mundo"]
     Olá Mundo
     [(),()]
     ```

     (Nota: você pode querer usar seqüência_ em vez disso, como no caso acima, se suas ações só retornarem `()`)
   - **Execute uma ação de IO em cada elemento de uma lista.**

     Você poderia mapear a função IO na sua lista (resultando em uma lista  de ações) e depois executá-la usando o truque acima. Mas é muito mais simples fazer isso:
        `mapM  my_action xs` ou `mapM_ my_action xs` onde `mapM f xs = sequence (map f xs)` e da mesma forma para `sequence_`.
2. ***Notas sobre velocidade***

   Listas ***Haskell*** são listas comuns de link único. (Procure o termo em qualquer livro sobre estruturas de dados.) Isso lhes dá certas propriedades de velocidade que valem a pena conhecer.

   2.1. **Operações rápidas**
      As seguintes operações são sempre rápidas:

   - **Prefira 1 elemento (o`:`operador)**
   - **`head` (pegue primeiro elemento)**
   - **`tail` (remova o primeiro elemento)**
     2.2. **Operações mais lentas**

     Qualquer função que faça algo com o N-ésimo elemento ou os primeiros N elementos geralmente fica mais lenta à medida que N aumenta. O seguinte tudo abrandar como `n` fica maior:
   - **`xs !! n`**
   - **`take n xs`**
   - **`drop n xs`**
   - **`splitAt n xs`**

     Qualquer função que precise processar toda a lista obviamente fica mais lenta à medida que a lista fica maior. O seguinte tudo abrandar como a lista `xs` fica maior:
   - **`length xs`**
   - **`list1 ++ list2`** (a velocidade depende apenas do tamanho de list1)
   - **`last xs`**
   - **`map my_fn xs`**
   - **`filter my_test xs`**
   - **`zip my_fn list1 list2`** (a velocidade depende da menor das duas listas - assim como o tamanho da lista de resultados!)
   - **`x 'elem' xs`**
   - **`sum xs`**
   - **`minimum xs`**
   - **`maximum xs`**

Comment: É preciso uma resposta tão longa assim?

Comment: Muito Obrigado eu só estava pensando em como não ser ofensivo... kkkkkkk